# Android : setVolume and setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);

Tags: android, volume, android-audiomanager

I am playing  an audio file with an internal speaker using this code

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
```

How can I set the volume?

Answer (score 2):

Use `adjustStreamVolume()` on `AudioManager`.

Though, preferably, you let the user set the volume the normal way, via the volume control buttons. You can indicate what stream that is to control in your activity via `setVolumeControlStream()`.

Comment: I use this ? 
audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, 0);
but how can I set the volume level ?

Answer (score 1):

am2 is an instance of AudioManager system service.
am2 = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

```
// makes the media volume adjustment
public static int setVolume(int inputVol, Context sender) {
    int outVol;
    if (inputVol < 0)
        inputVol = 0;
    if (inputVol > am2.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC))
        inputVol = am2.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    am2.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, inputVol,
            AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
    outVol = am2.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    return outVol;
}
```